# Registry keys: PowerShell different from RegEdit

Tags: powershell, registry, regedit

I'm getting different results when I interrogate my registry, depending on the method used. Why is this? Is it some 32-bit v 64-bit trickiness? How do I get the RegEdit answers via PowerShell?

**Method 1 - RegEdit**

If I browse to HKLM\SOFTWARE in RegEdit.exe, I see a list of subkeys, starting with:

```
7-Zip
Alps
```

**Method 2 - PowerShell**

```
ForEach-Object{Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE'} | Select PSChildName
```

produces a list, starting with:

```
Adobe
ATI
```

**Method 3 - reg query**

Just for fun I tried a third method I discovered while hunting on Stack Overflow for an answer:

```
reg query hklm\SOFTWARE
```

returns a list, starting with:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ATI
```

Comment: There is a separate 32/64 registry, with certain keys shared into both. Also check you are running administrator for each of your 3 methods.

Comment: Regedit combines the 32 bit and 64 bit registry entries. You can access the 32 bit applications on reg or powershell by querying `HKLM\software\WOW6432Node` take a look here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305097

Comment: I suppose this would be dependent on the shell you are running as well. I would suggest testing with the 32bit and 64bit shells of powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to user3211152 and Matt...

I can see the 32-bit keys under the `HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node`. But also, I discovered that I was running my PowerShell in the *Windows PowerShell ISE (x86)* shell. When I changed to the *Windows PowerShell ISE* shell, I could see the other data (ie the same my RegEdit example in my question).